# End of Json string identification

Tags: c, json

Json string : "{\n\t"tag": "Value",\n\t"attributes": {\n\t\t"rfid": "2"\n\t},\n\t"dat": "1"\n}

I am receiving the Json string from web server part by part i.e 8bytes at a time

When i am trying to collect the data in one buffer with the below logic in C

```
static char *jsonString ;
bool found_json = false;
jsonString = (char*)malloc (1024, sizeof(char));

while(data[i] != "}")
{
    found_json = true;
    for( i = 0; i< len; i++)
    {
        memcpy(jsonString, data, len);
    }       
    
}
```

can someday throw some light that how to detect end of the string of Json as there will be two closing Json object

Comment: `malloc()` takes one argument, not two.

Comment: How do *you* do it, looking at the string?

Comment: `found_json = true;` You do this on every character that is not a closing `'}'`. That doesn't seem useful. You don't care about how many opening `'{'` you found so far. That is important. For a simple implementation you can just count `'{'` and `'}'` and if number of `'}'` reaches number of `'{'` you are done. Assuming the string is valid.

Comment: You could do some brute force approach by just throwing your input string into some JSON lib and see if you get an error. If not, you must have received a complete JSON string. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think you have two proper ways: either fully parse the JSON (you can use some libraries for that) or somehow receive the length of the string (if this is a HTTP request then there should be `Content-Length` header which indicates the length). Things like messing  with curly braces is not reliable because even a simple number like `1233` or boolean values like `true` are valid JSON strings.

Comment: fisrt i need to receive full JSON string in  one buffer then only i can parse and this request is coming from http request but there is no option for content length and this json string is receive part by part i.e 8 bytes at a time

Comment: Don't know what kind if parser are you using, but some have error codes like "inout too short". You might read your input until you don't receive that error code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some pseudo code for finding the end of your string:

```
open = 0;
close = 0;

while ( visit each character in your buffer )
{
  if (new character == '{')
    open++;
  else if (new character == '}')
    close++;

  if (open == 0) // Did we even start the JSON string yet?
    discard character
  else if (open == close) // Matching number of { and } found. We are done.
  {
    process JSON string
    open = close = 0; // Prepare for next incoming JSON string.
  }
}
```

Comment: This will not work for JSONs like { ”something": "}" }.

Comment: @sdobak Yes, if that is a valid input, the OP also needs to care about content of strings. Properly identifying strings (including escaped `\"´) takes a bit more effort.

Comment: Well, OP is using it with a web server. If that server is on the open internet then he should be prepared for every possible input. 